# Quite simple test to know sudo

Tags: bash, permissions, sudo

I Have user allowed to sudo ALL on behalf of www-data.

`USERALIAS  ALL=(www-data) ALL`

However, these 2 executions have different results:

```
$ sudo -uwww-data touch /tmp/test
$ sudo -uwww-data echo "anothertest" > /tmp/test2
```

Guess who owns each resulting file ?

```
ls -l /tmp/test*
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 0 dic 18 16:21 /tmp/test
-rw-r--r-- 1 user   user   5 dic 18 16:22 /tmp/test2
```

why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second example, the user `www-data` executed the command

```
echo "anothertest"
```

and it was `user` that redirected the output of the command to the file `/tmp/test2`.  That would explain the file ownership in the (second) case.  In the first one, it was `www-data` that created the file `/tmp/test`.

It's not clear what you're expecting, but if you wanted that `/tmp/test2/` be owned by `www-data`, execute a shell command instead:

```
sudo -uwww-data sh -c 'echo "anothertest" > /tmp/test2'
```

Comment: Your code is right! I misunderstood the chain/piping of commands executed through sudo. However  my stupid test was just to know why my `export SVN_SSH="ssh -p2022"; sudo -uwww-data sh -c 'svn up'` is failing with the typical message `svn: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option...` as if the export (I have `Defaults env_keep +="svn_ssh"` in visudo) wasn't working

Comment: @shriek It seems that you want to say: sudo -uwww-data SVN_SSH="ssh -p2022" sh -c 'svn up'

Comment: Sure ! Thanks everybody. My brain is getting elder and gets confused with the simplest ....and even the most difficult things ! :D